# MVC Framework concept to create Local database

Tags: javascript, database, html, javascriptmvc

Is it possible to create a local database using MVC framework concepts in javascript + html5

Regards

Ravindran

Comment: Do you mean html5 local storage or an actual database?

Comment: Its HTML5 Local Database .. not local storage (key, value)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the target browser. See this presentation for a quick update,

```
Your browser, your storage
[http://www.slideshare.net/fullo/your-browser-your-storage-9574181][1]
```

Apple has a nice Offline Calendar demo that demonstrates the use of Web SQL Storage

```
Safari Technology Demos - Offline Calendar
[http://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/offline-calendar.php][2]
```